# Character movement in the 2.5D game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like the figure to only move along the X axis

I have this code:

```
var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
transform.position += new Vector3(movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed, 0, 0);
```

But the figure somehow moves strangely in different directions. What could be wrong? My Y axis is set to 0

Comment: Please define "moving strangely in different directions" a bit better. Have you tried logging the location of the figure or attaching a debugger?

Comment: Try to watch in inspector how your transform changing. Maybe camera looking at object from wrong angle?

Answer (score 0):

You are using += so if your starting position isn't 0 you will add the starting value:
this

```
transform.position += new Vector3(movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed, 0, 0);
```

translates to

```
transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed, 0, 0);
```

you should do

```
Vector3 temp = transform.position + new Vector3(movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed, 0, 0);
transform.position =new Vector3(temp.x,transform.position.y,0);
```

or in short

```
transform.position=new Vector3(transform.position.x+movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed,transform.position.y,0)
```